# Tailwind: Mobile classes overriding responsive classes

Tags: tailwind-css

Tailwind has started acting up on my latest project and after hours of debugging I can't figure out what's happening.

When I have this:

```
 <div class='fixed bottom-0 right-6 sm:relative sm:block'>
```

The div is always fixed, regardless of the screen size. In this:

```
<div class='hidden sm:flex'>
OR
<div class='hidden sm:block'>
```

The div is always hidden, regardless of the screen size.

However, for borders and text-colors responsiveness works. Is that expected behavior?

This is my tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    purge: [
      './resources/**/*.blade.php',
      './resources/**/*.js',
      './resources/**/*.vue',
    ],
    darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
    theme: {
        fontFamily: {
            'mont': 'Montserrat',
            'open': 'Open Sans',
            'roboto': 'Roboto',
            'lato': 'Lato',
        },
        extend: {
            colors: {
                'xmas-red': '#b71a3b',
                'xmas-dark-red': '#7e0f12',
                'xmas-brown': '#bc6d4c',
                'xmas-olive': '#6a7045',
                // 'xmas-gray': '#313c33',
                'xmas-gray': '#364739',
                'xmas-blue': '#072b54'
            },
            width: {
                '124': '60rem',
            },
            height: {
                '100': '36rem'
            }
        },
    },
    variants: {
        extend: {
            opacity: ['disabled'],
            backgroundColor: ['disabled'],
            borderColor: ['disabled'],
            textColor: ['disabled'],
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        require('@tailwindcss/forms')
    ],
}
```

Comment: Share the contents of you `tailwind.config.js` file as well, the code you shared works fine with proper configuration.

Comment: @JHeth shared my config.

Comment: There are a few errors in your config that don't affect responsive utilities: under `fontFamily` all of your fonts are declared as strings, they need to be arrays, also `Open Sans` needs to be `Open\\ Sans` or `"Open Sans"` [here's the docs on it](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#:~:text=Tailwind%20does%20not%20automatically%20escape%20font%20names). But my only thought is that you're purging classes in dev mode, try turning purge into an object and setting enabled to false as shown [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production#enabling-manually).